# PHP Prepared Statements with while loop

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am doing some work in php with prepared statements. My task is to first select some data from one table and then insert the data into another table. How can I use while loop in prepared statement to insert the records?

Here is the code:

```
stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT userid, order_number, balance from plus_wallet  limit 0,3");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userid, $orderid, $balance);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $stmt1=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `plus_user_wallet`(`userid`, `balance`, `update_time`) VALUES (?,?, NOW() + INTERVAL 45000 second)");
    $stmt1->bind_param('ss' , $userid, $balance);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->close();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Please show some code, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: bro we are not magician... we can't read your mind... post your code..

Comment: i have provided the code.. please check the code and help me

Comment: Your `while` loop does not close.

Comment: @eisberg: it is closed. check in the end of the question. it came out of the script.

Comment: actually my question is how can i execute my insert query in prepared statement in while loop. as we do in procedural style.

Comment: So you close `$stmt` in every iteration? That seems very wrong.

Comment: No .. I am actually using the loop in prepared statement for the first time.otherwise i used different $stmt for different query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `order_number` field is not required anywhere else and you're selecting it because it's in the table, you could use:

```
insert into
plus_user_wallet
    (userid,balance,update_time) 
select 
    userid,balance,now()+interval 45000 second
from
    plus_wallet
limit
    0,3;
```

You could make that into a prepared statement if you require a single `userid` value by adding `where userid=?` into the select statement after `from plus_wallet`

Obviously, if you do require the order_number for elsewhere then you will need a loop system.

A few notes regarding your code:

- Prepare `$stmt1` outside of the while loop - that's the point of a prepared statement
- Close all prepared statements after the while loop is complete

Comment: its awesome.. it did worked for me... and i came to learn something new .. amazing..

Comment: @daveboy: please be my mentor. and teach me php & mysql.. if it is possible. it would be great to learn from you.

Comment: ok.. it was great.. how can i write this code in prepared statement style ...?? please forgive me as i am not very good with prepared statements and not familiar with it...

Comment: i think it works with limit only. ok.. that's fine.. but i have a number of records, say more than 10lakhs ,, then?? please reply asap.. i want to insert the data from plus_wallet to plus_user wallet in prepared statement, using while loop. how it can be done with the help of while loop as we do in procedural style...

Comment: I can't be your mentor as I don't have time. Buy some books on PHP and SQL and they will help you more than I ever can. If you purely want to transfer all the records from plus_wallet across to plus_user_wallet then take off the `limit` clause. If you want a specific userid then add `where userid=?` after `from plus_wallet` and then bind the param as you do above. As I said, prepare the query and bind the parameter outside the `while` loop and close the statement after.

Comment: @daveboy: books never had helped me.. if you need any student prefer me.. it will be an honour to learn from you

Comment: @VishalParkash - Seriously, I don't have time. if books don't help you then think of a project which covers a lot of what you want to do (e.g. library system, asset tracking etc) and work on it. Get a book just for reference *or* download the PHP and MySQL manuals from the relevant sites so you don't continually need to be online. Remember - if you encounter a problem then someone else has already had it and fixed it. Google is your friend